# Why are apt-get repositories hardcoded to a specific release?

Tags: apt, accessibility, usability, maintenance

From the usability point of view, I do not understand why on each release upgrade you have to manually patch all the URLs of apt in order to make them point to the newer distribution.

Why is not possible for apt to auto-detect the current and use it, so when you upgrade there is no need to upgrade the urls anymore?

Comment: What is hardcoded where? what URLs do you have to patch manually?

Comment: The question has 2 answers. I don't see a reason to close this as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand why on each release upgrade you have to manually
>   patch all the URLs of apt in order to make them point to the newer
>   distribution.

You do not have to do this. (Not typically, anyway.) Actually, in Ubuntu, manually changing release names in `sources.list` is not a supported way to upgrade, and may often not work.

When the package manager checks to see what package versions are available to be installed or upgraded to, `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any configuration files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` are consulted to discover which software sources are configured. This includes but is not limited to information about what release is installed, and occasionally (though not usually!) it even makes sense to have software sources configured for releases other than the one you are running.

When you upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release using a supported method (such as the Software Updater / Update Manager or the `do-release-upgrade` command), the release names in `sources.list` are changed automatically. Some software sources, such as PPAs, may instead be disabled.

One of the reasons Ubuntu's package manager doesn't just check which release is installed and use that information dynamically to determine what software sources to use, is that there is no *one thing* that is the release you are running. Normally, which Ubuntu release you're using (e.g., 14.04) is well defined. But during a release upgrade, and under some other circumstances (some pathological and others proper), you may have a mixture of different releases.

In order for Ubuntu to get the point in a release upgrade where you are really, truly, and definitively running the next release (i.e., the release upgrade target), or even to the point where commonly used indicators like the contents of `/etc/lsb-release` would indicate the target release, it must *first* change what software sources are configured (to those of the target release) and upgrade, install, and remove packages to reflect what is provided by those software sources.

Comment: Just to add (although off topic), Debian has set it up so that you can either go by the release (Wheezy, Jessie, Sid, etc.) or by the series (`stable`, `testing`, `unstable`). The series is changed with the distribution that is considered to be that series (in other words, the stable distribution) is changed. This isn't technically hard, as this is just a simple symlink. As to why Ubuntu might not do this, it might be cases like now, where there are two LTS releases, and either could be considered stable.

Comment: However, note that Ubuntu does have a special keyword for the development release ([devel](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/devel/)) that you can use to stay on the development, **unreleased** distribution (effectively a rolling distro).

Comment: I think the OP was referring to what `do-release-upgrade` effectively does behind the scenes (among a few other things), and that the distro has to be changed.

Comment: @saiarcot895 seems to indicate what I was looking for, being able to use a placeholder inside the .list files so you could stay on "current" release and not have to patch them each time you upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Not every repository you add needs to be an official Ubuntu one. Take for example Oracle Virtualbox: at each Ubuntu release, the repository is updated with some days (or weeks) of delay. But in the meantime, the "old" repository works just fine. Being able to state which release you want to query in this case is essential.

> Why is not possible for apt to auto-detect the current and use it, so when you upgrade there is no need to upgrade the urls anymore?

This is done automatically both from the GUI (`sudo update-manager`) and from the command line (`sudo do-release-upgrade`) for what concerns official repositories. You can do it manually, but you don't need to.

Comment: It seems that it does not really work as expected. I was looking to a smart solution that doesn't work only with official repositories. If apt would be able to detect releases from remove repository, it could pick the best option. it can even have a configurable preference.

Comment: Actually you asked for a "why", not for a "solution". Unofficial repositories are automatically commented out during the upgrade, so in any case you need to have a look on them. This is of course because it's not smart for the system updater to blindly change their entries hoping that they will work (there are many examples like the Virtualbox one).

Comment: You are right that I asked why, not as in how to fix it. I was I was looking more to a link to feature request. From the technical point of view it should be possible to make it work smart (as in detecting matching releases, so you would not have to fix them manually).